# Is it possible to extend a default layout xml in magento

Tags: magento-1.9

Is it possible to extend a default layout xml or any default xml like page xml in magento? Not overriding them.

I would like to create a different template for specific pages in Magento.

Comment: Generally the XMLs are not overridden, they are rather merged before the final rendering. It should be perfectly fine to add or remove elements you want to the same handle in separate XML files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you had replaced `<yourmodule>` by `<page>` the resulting file would have looked :

```
<config>
<!-- some nodes... -->
<!-- some nodes... -->
<!-- some nodes... -->
    <frontend>
        <layout>
             <updates>
                  <page>
                        <file>yourlayout.xml</file>
                  </page>
                  <!-- some layout updates nodes from other config files... -->
             </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
<!-- some nodes... -->
<!-- some nodes... -->
</config>
```

[See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2934161/magento-layout-override)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of change of default layout xml or override them,You can use custom layout  for any page which can be found on page design tab ( page layout ).CMS->Pages page->Your Page (Any page you want to change the layout)->Design(on left 3rd tab)-> page layout put you XML code here..
For XML layout pattern Magento [here](http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/demystifying-magentos-layout-xml-part-1/)..

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really good in Magento frontend templating, however, every time I create a new template I tried to copy the default xml and modify them in my new template folder.

Maybe this technique is not a good practice, but for me, it is the most simplest and effective way to modify everything.